# How can I export vcards for multiple contacts?

Tags: search-results

When viewing a single contact, I can select "Actions" Vcard and export a vcard which can then be used in other applications (Outlook, OwnCloud, etc)

I would like to be able to select "Create Vcard" in the drop down list for actions for search results, and get a vcard file of many contacts that could be imported into other apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This option does not exist (as yet).I'm not aware of an extension to do this either. Your options include:

a. Write an extension that adds the above functionality

b. Use the api to export the data into a program that can generate multiple vcards and use that

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extension vcard-export. See https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/vcard-export .